# Saltos en un campo de una tabla

Tags: mysql

Buenos días, Soy nuevo en este sitio, quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar o orientar con esta duda.

Tengo una tabla en `MYSQL` llamese `Facturas`, tienen un campo llamado NUMERO DE FACTURA(`NUMFAC`), entre otros, el campo guarda un carácter que identifica el estatus de la factura, para la factura pagadas el primer carácter es una letra `P`, ahora bien lo que quiero es saber si a través de un select se puede hacer algo, se puede obtener si hay saltos de facturas en un rango de fechas.

Les dejo como esta estructurada la tabla mas o menos.

```
+------------------------------------+  
|..Fecha...|Hora|.NumFac.|  
|2017-07-25|0801|P0000001|  
|2017-07-25|0802|P0000002|  
|2017-07-25|0810|P0000003|  
|2017-07-25|0811|P0000004|  
|2017-07-25|0812|P0000005|  
|2017-07-25|0813|P0000007|  
|2017-07-26|0802|P0000008|  
|2017-07-26|0806|P0000009|  
|2017-07-26|0807|P0000010|  
|2017-07-26|0808|P0000011|  
|2017-07-26|0810|P0000012|  
|2017-07-26|0811|P0000013|  
|2017-07-26|0812|P0000014|
```

Comment: Creo que no lo tengo claro,lo que quieres es una query que,en este caso, devuelva `P0000006` ?

Comment: A ver si entendí. ¿lo que estás buscando es de alguna manera marcar que número de factura falta de acuerdo a la correlatividad?

Answer (score 0):

Esta query te devolvería todos los números de factura no existentes (incluyendo el siguiente al ultimo, este se podría eliminar si es necesario). La query funciona en `SqlServer`, pero imagino que para `MySql` será similar y fácilmente adaptable, y te puede dar una idea de una forma de conseguir lo que buscas:

```
select 'P' + replicate('0', 7 - len(substring(NumFac,2,7) +1)) + cast (substring(NumFac,2,7) +1 as varchar) From Facturas t1
where not exists (select * from Facturas t2 where substring(t1.NumFac,2,7) +1 = substring(t2.NumFac,2,7));
```